# ¿Quiero que los anuncios de tercero cuando le den clic se abran el enlace en una ventana modal?

Tags: modal, navegador-web, enlace, ventana

Algunos de ustedes me pueden ayudar con el código que cuando le den clic a los anuncio de tercero se abran en una ventana modal.

Comment: Debes colocar lo que has intentado de código. Generalmente no se responden preguntas de la manera que estás redactando la tuya porque se presta a pensar que deean que les hagamos las tareas. Modifica tu pregunta.